# solr 5 post.jar simple post tool error when indexing java extension

Tags: solr

2.1 in windows 7
 what I was trying to do is indexing java extension file using post.jar posting tool
what I tried:

```
java -Dauto=yes -Dc=java -Ddata=files -Dfiletypes=java -Drecursive=yes -java post.jar abc.jar
```

it gives me error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

I also tried extensions like xyz, and it worked but only java extension does not work
it just does not like java extension?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to index jar files?

Comment: @Ramzy java files I just wrote wrong in the content, I fiexed it